# Publish free and paid version android apk with same keystore?

Tags: android

I read many post on SOF about how to handle free and paid version of eclipse android projects.
But can't find any post about the use of keystore approach for free/paid version.

The different of free and paid in my application is the Admob in one layout.xml.

Finally, i choose a safe way (in my opinion..)

Let's say my project name : ProjectX

1. I clone the sources via GIT to ProjectX_Free and ProjectX_Paid
2. Import 2 projects above to eclipse.
3. Do some pre-publish works.(enable ProGuard, disable debug etc)
4. Change the package name to com.company.ProjectX_Free and
       com.company.ProjectX_Paid.
5. Remove the admob code in paid version.
6. Right click the project, export signed APK via eclipse's android
       tools.

Eclipse will ask for create or use exist keystore to create APK.

So should i use same keystore for them?

What is the Pros and Cons?

Thanks you for help.

Comment: for that you can use inapp purchase like in gaming it's use to acces some level we have to purchase that level like that you can make you apps

Comment: Um..i have think about that,but base on user's habits. User would like buy in Google Play rather than In-App purchase. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the Signing Strategies section of the [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) guide.

> In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the expected lifespan of your applications.